# Validation on form submit using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form and I am adding rows by cloning it. I have one drop-down value in my form too. I want to add two validation on my form

1. If the user doesn't fill all the fields , he should not be able to add another row (keeping in mind that user should also not be allowed to add another row if the drop-down value is set to the default value).
2. On form submit I want the same validation that if there is any field which is left empty or the default value of the drop-down is selected, the user should not be able to submit the form.

I have tried this but still it contains lots of bugs in it, as I am new to jQuery.

```
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
    var cindex = 0;
    var quicklink = '' ;
    $(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
      var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;

      if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=description]').attr('selected','selected')){
    {
        alert("Please fill the current row");
        return false;
      }}

        var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
        var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
         $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
        cindex++;
        $clone.find('input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
        $clone.find('input:button').attr('disabled', true);
        $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
        //update ids of elements in row
        $clone.find("*").each(function() {
                var id = this.id || "";
                if(id != ""){

                var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                if (match.length == 2) {
                this.id = this.name + (cindex);
                }
                }
        });
       $tr.after($clone);

    });
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
function disableField(e)
{ var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
    if (Count == 2){
    $(e).closest('tr').find("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);

    }else{
    $(e).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
}}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------


   $(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
     $(this).closest("tr").remove();
     var Count1 = $('#dataTable tr').length;
     if (Count1 == 2){
     $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', true);
     }

    });

//---------------------------------------------------------------------.

function fnOnSubmit() {
var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=description]').attr('selected','selected')){
{
        alert("Please fill all the fields");
        return false;
      }}

var flag='';
$('#dataTable input:not([type=button]),#dataTable select').each(function () {

      flag = flag + (this.value) + '~';
        quicklink = flag;
  });
   document.frmmain.quicklink.value = quicklink;

    SendTxnRequest('02','QWC'); 
}
```

**`HTML`**

```js
 var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9 _-]+)$/;
        var cindex = 0;
        var quicklink = '' ;
        $(document).on('click','.Buttons', function(addrow) {
          var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
          
          if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=description]').attr('selected','selected')){
     {
            alert("Please fill the current row");
            return false;
          }}
         
            var $tr    = $('#dataTable tbody tr:last');
            var $clone = $tr.clone(true);
       $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
            cindex++;
         $clone.find('input:text').val('').attr('disabled', true);
      $clone.find('input:button').attr('disabled', true);
            $clone.attr('id', 'id'+(cindex) ); //update row id if required
            //update ids of elements in row
            $clone.find("*").each(function() {
                    var id = this.id || "";
                    if(id != ""){
        
                    var match = id.match(regex) || [];
                    if (match.length == 2) {
           this.id = this.name + (cindex);
                    }
                    }
            });
           $tr.after($clone);
         
        });
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    function disableField(e)
    { var Count = $('#dataTable tr').length;
        if (Count == 2){
     $(e).closest('tr').find("input").not('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', false);
            
        }else{
     $(e).closest('tr').find("input").prop('disabled', false);
    }}
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    
       $(document).on("click", '.DeleteButton', function() {
         $(this).closest("tr").remove();
      var Count1 = $('#dataTable tr').length;
      if (Count1 == 2){
      $('.DeleteButton').prop('disabled', true);
      }
      
        });
    
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------.
    
    function fnOnSubmit() {
    var count = $('table tr:last input:text').filter((_,el) => el.value.trim() == "").length;
    if(count || !$('.id_100 option[value=description]').attr('selected','selected')){
    {
            alert("Please fill all the fields");
            return false;
          }}
     
    var flag='';
    $('#dataTable input:not([type=button]),#dataTable select').each(function () {
    
       flag = flag + (this.value) + '~';
      quicklink = flag;
      });
       document.frmmain.quicklink.value = quicklink;
      
     SendTxnRequest('02','QWC'); 
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" id="dataTable" name="dataTable" class="graphtable">
      <thead>
    
        <tr>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Links</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="32%">Desciption</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">Image</td>
          <td class="headingalign" width="16%">URL</td>
       <td class="headingalign" width="05%"></td>
    
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      
        <tr id="id0" class="vals" name="id0">
     
          <td>
       <div class="id_100">
        <select type="select-one" id='fldsearch' class="objselect" name="fldsearch" onChange="disableField(this)" >
      <option value="">Select</option>
      
       
       <option value="">Guides </option>
           
       <option value="">Latest Offers </option>
     
      </select>
         </div> </td>
          <td>
            <input id="flddesc" name="flddesc" maxlength="500"  disabled="true" class="objinputtext1" size="85" value=""  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input  id="fldimg" name="fldimg" maxlength="50"  disabled="true" class="objinputtext2" size="45" value=""  />
      
          </td>
          <td>
            <input id="fldurl" name="fldurl" maxlength="55" disabled="true" class="objinputtext3" size="40" value=""  />
            
          </td>
       <td>
       <input tabindex="6" value="Delete Row" disabled="true" class="DeleteButton"  type="button" />
       </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>  
      <div class="buttonarea">
      <ul>
        <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button3" value="Add New Row" class="Buttons" name="Button3" type="button" /></li>
      <li><input tabindex="6" id="Button5" value="Initiate" class="buttons" name="Button5" type="button" onclick="return fnOnSubmit();"/></li>
         
    
      </ul>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle for your problem

Comment: I have added my code in snippet

Comment: At the moment, all the fields are disabled so you can't enter anything, why are you doing that?

Comment: Also, why are you using a `<table>` when you want a `<form>`?

Comment: my `<table>` is inside the `<form>`

Comment: Also the disabled field get enabled when a value from drop-down is selected